# Validation test failure for build of jq-1.5 on FreeBSD 9.x... Now what?

Tags: installation, jq

A note in the README file said to ask questions here, so I am doing so.

The RIPEstat service has just shut off their own port 43 plain text service and now is forcing everyone to access their data using jq.  I have **zero** experience with or knowledge of jq, but I am forced to give it a try.  I have just built the thing successfully from sources (jq-1.5) on my crusty old FreeBSD 9.x system and the build completed OK, but one of the post-build verification tests (tests/onigtest) failed.  I am looking at the test-suite.log file but none of what's in there means anything to me.  (Unfortunately, I am new to stackoverflow also, and thus, I have no idea how to even upload a copy of that here so that the maintainer can peruse it.)

So, my questions:

1)  Should I even worry about the failure of tests/onigtest?

2)  If I should, then what should I do about this failure?

3)  What is the best and/or most proper way for me to get a copy of the test-suite.log file to the maintainer(s)?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I even worry about the failure of tests/onigtest?

If the only failures are related to onigtest, then most likely only the regex filters will be affected.

> what should I do about this failure?

According to the jq [download page](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/), there is a pre-built binary for FreeBSD, so you might try that.

From your brief description, it's not clear to me what exactly you did, but if you haven't already done so, you might also consider building an executable from a git clone of "master" as per the guidelines on the download page; see also https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Installation#or-build-from-source

> What is the best and/or most proper way for me to get a copy of the test-suite.log file to the maintainer(s)?

You could create a ticket at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues